# bootstrap input group with text select and button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have this using bootstrap css:

[image: bootstrap input group]

I've written a jsfiddle to make my tests :
http://jsfiddle.net/xr4uofje/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="input-group-addon" size="8" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <select class="form-control"></select>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Get</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can put this type of elements

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MansukhKhandhar/4309n31p/1/)**

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group my-group"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snpid" placeholder="Test"/>
            <select id="lunch" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunch ...">
                <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
                <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
                <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
                <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
                <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
            </select> 
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default my-group-button" type="submit">GO!</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.my-group .form-control{
    width:50%;
}
```

JQUERY

```
if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
    $(".my-group-button").css("height","+=1px");
}
```

Comment: That's great man! I've struggle a bit on that and never found out about the width: 50% !

Comment: Can I be a bit picky and ask you if it is possible to have a one pixel border between the input and the select? How would you do that? Overriding the input css in order to remove a border-right?

Comment: For bootstrap 5 custom-select has changed to form-select

Answer (score 6):

as document [said](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups).

> Avoid using `<select>` elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.

so we should use bootstrap's dropdowns with javascript code instead.