# bootstrap input group select field,text field and search field

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to build search bar similar to amazon site.

A select input field followed by input field followed by search button.

[image: search bar]

this is what I have got so far:[image: this is what I have got so far]

The issue is that the button1 dropdown is not a select input field if I do change to input field everything breaks.

examples in bootstrap site dont show group with input field select but dropdown menu.

## my code

```
 <div class="input-group input-group-lg">

        <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle custom" data-toggle="dropdown">Button 1 <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
    </span>


        </div>
```

## css - to remove curve radius for center input field or buttons

```
.custom{
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap input group with text select and button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511300/bootstrap-input-group-with-text-select-and-button)

Answer (score 2):

Please have look at my demo. If you want add your style then add class to components to change there style.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Apps & Games <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works ok, but the selector is not automatically picking the selected list item.

Comment: you have to play with some javascript or jquery code for get exact output

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved just amazon like search using this:

```
<div class="input-group my-group"> 

            <select id="filter_type" name="filter_type" class="selectpicker form-control" style="width:30%;">
                        <option value>Select Filter Type..</option>
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="firstname">First Name</option>
                        <option value="lastname">Last Name</option>
                        <option value="email">Email</option>

                    </select>
            <select id="search" name="search" class="selectpicker form-control" disabled="disabled" style="width:70%;  display:block;">
                       <option value>select filter type first</option>
                       </select>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:70%; display:none" name="searchfield" id="searchfield" placeholder="Enter username...">

             <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  disabled="disabled" type="submit">Filter</button>
  </span>

        </div>
```